# HTTP request using Python on Windows sometimes gives WinError 100601

Tags: python, windows, proxy, python-requests, firewall

This is the first time I am trying Python on Windows. I want to download a png file from the web. Here is the Python3 program:

```
import requests

url_1 = 'https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/9FB3/production/_105038804_titled-624-nc.png'

url_2 = 'https://randomuser.me/img/creator_keith.png'
res = requests.get(url_1)
print (res.status_code)
# Lets try for url_2
res = requests.get(url_2)
print (res.status_code)
```

This works for url_1 but fails for url_2 with the error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='randomuser.me', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /img/creator_keith.png (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))

I understand this might be a firewall or proxy issue. But my question is why it works for some websites but not for others? BTW this works fine for url_1 and url_2 on Linux.

Thanks in advance,
dksr

Comment: You're using `https`.  Does your Windows machine have proper certificates installed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be specific on "sometimes", how often you are trying to call URLs? Were you able to get the results sometimes?

I am assuming servers are up and running.
Whenever you do a requests.get, a tcp connection is created and when you repeatedly call requests.get, it will create multiple tcp connections, which degrades the performance and might give HTTPSConnectionPool errors. You could try [Python request's session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/), it will persist the tcp connection created for reuse.

Comment: I mean, it works for some URLs but not for others. I thought its a  proxy/firewall issue. But in that case it should fail for all URLs. I also thought it might be for different file types I was trying to download (ex: csv, png etc), but it works for some png and won't work for some.

Comment: Have you checked if you have proper certificates installed as suggested by @John Gordon